# Functional way to check if array of numbers is sequential

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

Let's say that an array is sequential when each successful element has the value of previous element `+ 1`. Suppose I have an array of numbers like `{5,6,7,8}` (sequential) or `{1,2,5}` (not sequential).

Is there a nice functional way to check if the array is sequential? I can do it with the following code:

```
bool IsSequential(int[] array)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
       if (array[i] != array[i - 1] + 1)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

I'm trying to determine if a poker hand is straight.

Comment: possible duplicate of [make sure array is sequential in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413272/make-sure-array-is-sequential-in-c-sharp)

Comment: How do you deal with the ace? If its value is 1, you can't use this method to detect an ace-high straight.

Comment: Your code is simple and work perfectly

Comment: Just use the code you already have - it's fine.

Comment: Is an empty array may be considered sequential?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    bool IsSequential(int[] array)
    {
        return array.Zip(array.Skip(1), (a, b) => (a + 1) == b).All(x => x);
    }
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: If you don't use `Skip`, you're just comparing elements with themselves, which of course will always be equal.

Comment: Just to add, this will not work if the array of ints is not in order. e.g. this would work with `[4,5,6]` but not with `[5,4,6]`. You can just use `array.OrderBy(a => a).Zip(array.Skip(1), (a, b) => (a + 1) == b).All(x => x);` to get the latter to work.

Comment: For this to also work for decreasing sequential arrays, use `return array.Zip(array.Skip(1), (a, b) => (a + 1) == b).All(x => x) || array.Zip(array.Skip(1), (a, b) => (a - 1) == b).All(x => x);`

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it's really an improvement/nicer but you could use Range.

```
ENumerable.Range(0, myArray.Length).Any(i => myArray[i] != myArray[0] + i)
```

This returns true if the array doesn't contain sequential number.

Comment: Nice, although if we want to check if an array _is_ sequential: `Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.Length).All(i => myArray[i] == myArray[0] + i)`

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq:

```
    public static bool IsSequential(int[] a)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, a.Length - 1).All(i => a[i] - 1 == a[i - 1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, for all sequential, non sequential data.  A complete example with sample input. **Tested and works fine**

```
var list = new List<int>(new[] { 7, 6, 5, 4, 3,9});
int minValue = list.Min();
int maxValue = list.Count;
List<int> test =  Enumerable.Range(minValue, maxValue).ToList();
var result = Enumerable.Range(minValue, maxValue).Except(list);
if (result.ToList().Count == 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("numbers are in sequence");
}
else
{               
   Console.WriteLine("Numbers are not in sequence");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as: [make sure array is sequential in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413272/make-sure-array-is-sequential-in-c-sharp)

Answer there:

**if you're sure that the array is sorted and has no duplicates**, you can just check:

```
array[array.Length - 1] == array[0] + array.Length - 1
```

Comment: That's wrong, with this you can't know anything about the other elements than first and last.

Comment: @Serge that's why specified: if you're sure that the array is sorted and has no duplicates. If so  - the answer is correct. Think why!

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(array[0], array[array.Length-1]).Except(array.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

First sort the array, remove N of a kind (e.g. pairs) using distinct() and If the array length is always == to 5 All you need to do is if((array[4] - array[0]) == 4) return true.

It gets more complicated if its texas holdem or if you need to account for both an ace high and ace low straight.