# c# check for a poker straight

Tags: c#, poker

I am trying to write a poker hand evaluation method in c#. I have managed to do this for every poker hand using linq except a straight. 
For those that don't play a straight is made up of 5 cards with increments of 1 for each card. Ace can be high or low.

I have created an object called card which has a suit, rank and value (J = 11, Q =12 etc..). My method will be passed a list of this object containing 7 cards (hole cards and the board.)

Another thing to bear in mind is that a straight can only be made if the player has a 5 or 10.

See below my methods for other poker hands and please let me know if you have an idea for the straight method. Pseudo code would be fine also.

---

```
public bool CheckPair(List<Card> cards)
{
    //see if exactly 2 cards card the same rank.
    return cards.GroupBy(card => card.Rank).Count(group => group.Count() == 2) == 1;
}

public bool CheckTwoPair(List<Card> cards)
{
    //see if there are 2 lots of exactly 2 cards card the same rank.
    return cards.GroupBy(card => card.Rank).Count(group => group.Count() >= 2) == 2;
}

public bool CheckTrips(List<Card> cards)
{
    //see if exactly 3 cards card the same rank.
    return cards.GroupBy(card => card.Rank).Any(group => group.Count() == 3);
}
public bool CheckStraight(List<Card> cards)
{
    // order by decending to see order
    var cardsInOrder = cards.OrderByDescending(a => a.Value).ToList();
    // check for ace as can be high and low
    if (cardsInOrder.First().Rank == "A")
    {
        // check if straight with ace has has 2 values
        bool highStraight = cards.Where(a => a.Rank == "K" || a.Rank == "Q" || a.Rank == "J" || a.Rank == "10").Count() == 4;
        bool lowStraight = cards.Where(a => a.Rank == "2" || a.Rank == "3" || a.Rank == "4" || a.Rank == "5").Count() == 4;
        // return true if straight with ace
        if (lowStraight == true || highStraight == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // check for straight here
        return true;
    }
    // no straight if reached here.
    return false;

}

public bool CheckFlush(List<Card> cards)
{
    //see if 5 or more cards card the same rank.
    return cards.GroupBy(card => card.Suit).Count(group => group.Count() >= 5) == 1;
}

public bool CheckFullHouse(List<Card> cards)
{
    // check if trips and pair is true
    return CheckPair(cards) && CheckTrips(cards);
}
public bool CheckQuads(List<Card> cards)
{
    //see if exactly 4 cards card the same rank.
    return cards.GroupBy(card => card.Rank).Any(group => group.Count() == 4);
}

// need to check same 5 cards
public bool CheckStraightFlush(List<Card> cards)
{
    // check if flush and straight are true.
    return CheckFlush(cards) && CheckStraight(cards);
}
```

Comment: Are you going this just for fun, or for real usage? Because for real usage there are existing libraries carefully designed to be very fast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Functional way to check if array of numbers is sequential](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225010/functional-way-to-check-if-array-of-numbers-is-sequential)

Comment: Hi, it's just for abit of a challange

Comment: `lowStraight == true` is equivalent to `lowStraight`, so write that instead.

Comment: Your current check for a straight with an Ace is incorrect, BTW.  As it stands AKQJJ would be counted as a straight.

Comment: This is very late but the check for two pair is also incorrect. In a 7 card per hand game (2 hole cards and 5 community cards), a player can have three pair but only the two highest pair count. For example, a player can have AAKKQQ2 cards as a valid hand but only AAKK are counted for the two pair.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the best performing check, but I'd say it's very readable which is usually a good property.

Just grab 5 cards, skipping cards you've already seen every iteration and check for a straight for each sequence. An ordered sequence is a straight if it does not contain doubles and if  the first and last cards difference is 5.

```
public bool CheckStraight(List<Card> cards)
{
     //maybe check 5 and 10 here first for performance

     var ordered = cards.OrderByDescending(a => a.Value).ToList();
     for(i = 0; i < ordered.Count - 5; i++) {
          var skipped = ordered.Skip(i);
          var possibleStraight = skipped.Take(5);
          if(IsStraight(possibleStraight)) {
               return true;
          }
     }
     return false;
}

public bool IsStraight(List<Card> fiveOrderedCards) {
     var doubles = cards.GroupBy(card => card.Rank).Count(group => group.Count() > 1);
     var inARow = cards[4] - cards[0] = 5; //Ace is 0

     return !doubles && inARow;
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to detect a 10-J-Q-K-A straight.

Comment: That's probably because it's not happy about the "A". Are you sure the "A" is moddeled as a 15 there? Perhaps my comment in the code where I say Ace = 0 makes  things confusing (lol). An Ace has to be equal to 0 when its a low straight, and 15 when it's a high straight. In what way you model that is up to you. (Hint: You could detect an ace and manually add it to the ordered list on both ends in the first method when the detection returns true).

Answer (score 0):

I have made some small changes to Glubus answer. The code below does the job however you will have to check manually for a wheel (A,1,2,3,4,5) straight.

```
public bool CheckStraight(List<Card> cards)
    {
        //maybe check 5 and 10 here first for performance

        var ordered = cards.OrderByDescending(a => a.Value).ToList();
        for (var i = 0; i < ordered.Count - 4; i++)
        {
            var skipped = ordered.Skip(i);
            var possibleStraight = skipped.Take(5).ToList();
            if (IsStraight(possibleStraight))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
public bool IsStraight(List<Card> cards)
{
    return cards.GroupBy(card => card.Value).Count() == cards.Count() && cards.Max(card => (int)card.Value) - cards.Min(card => (int)card.Value) == 4;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure to close your question, either by marking the question as answered or deleting the question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think about real one liner, since A can be 1 or 14, but this should be good:

```
int c = 5; // How many cards straight
bool Ais1 = cards.OrderBy(a => a.Value).Select((i,j) => i.Value-j).Distinct().Skip(1).Count() <= (cards.Count - c);
bool Ais14 = cards.OrderBy(a => (a.Value == 1 ? 14 : a.Value)).Select((i,j) => (i.Value == 1 ? 14 : i.Value)-j).Distinct().Skip(1).Count() <= (cards.Count - c);
return Ais1 || Ais14;
```

(Updated - thank you Janne, I've fixed the code)

Comment: BTW, if card will have {Rank, Value, HighValue} so {"A", 1, 14}, {"2", 2, 2} ... {"K", 13, 13} then code can look even nicer.

Answer (score 0):

erm,

```
function bool IsStraight(IEnumerable<int> cards)
{
    var orderedCards = cards.OrderBy(n => n).ToList();
    var test = orderdCards.Zip(orderdCards.Skip(1), (a, b) => b - a);

    var count = 0;
    foreach(var n in test)
    {
        if (n == 1)
        {
            count++;
            if (count == 4)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```